# Response of jquery ajax call in error method instead of sucess

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am calling jquery ajax to a page as given below

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function Showgrid() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "popup.aspx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {locale: 'en-US' },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
             $("#target").html(data.d);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);

            }
                    });

    }
</script>
```

And on popup.aspx page load I've written code as

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.Write(Request.QueryString[0]);
    Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

I am getting response but not in success method rather in error function
Please suggest what is wrong

Comment: Use Asp.net Pagemethods instead. Google for it.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `POST`, i.e. to `type: "POST"`. And in the page turn to `Response.Write(Request[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Your ouptut from the .aspx page is not json type. Use Json encoding before writting to the response or change the dataType : text

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, change type to POST and enclose the data in quotes. On the server side, you will need to call a web method. You can't use page_load as you're passing a parameter 'locale'. See below revised JSON function and Server Code (assuming the server side code you're using is correct):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void ShowGrid(string locale)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[0]);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

JSON:

```
function Showgrid() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "popup.aspx/ShowGrid",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{ 'locale': 'en-US' }",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#target").html(data.d);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);

        }
    });

}
```